# Android Webview crashes if placed in any Activity layout (since 22. March)

Tags: android, webview, crash

**nutshell:**

Problem: i can not build a working app that has webview, however they worked before 22 March.

**detailed:**

There is a known problem on last update of Webviews, the Webview developers made some mistakes, i found many topics about how to rollback WebView versions as a phone - user and such topics.

But i have not found any topic from developer point of view.

The thing is:

0. I have an application my gradle (imo prossible relevant parts):

   ```
    compileSdkVersion 29, buildToolsVersion "29.0.3", targetSdkVersion 29
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0-beta02'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-share:[5,6)'
    implementation "androidx.work:work-gcm:2.2.0"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'
    ...
   ```
1. i had a few activities using Webview, until 22 march they were working flawlessly.
2. On march 22 i was making my 20th build that day to my phone (Redmi 6 MIUI 11.0.4) and suddenly the app crashed, in a few hours (of undoing some modifications i made - thinking that was the problem) i realized that it is related to Webview, as if i remove from an activity that activity starts working.
3. I searched the net and i saw new posts about (user point of view) crashing Gmail and other apps because of WebViews.
4. I checked and
   a) all my earlier builds are still working (even the webviews are working fine! on same phone),
   b) and only the builds i made after that point are not working (on same phone).

So now i can not compile a working version form the app.
I suspect some wrong version of the Webview was downloaded automatically by AndroidStudio project, and all new builds uses that wrong version since 22. March.

Any ideas how to solve?
eg:

- can i force my builds to use the older version of WebView?
- OR how can i force it to get a new bug free version of WebView - is there any?

Thanks!

Comment: The `WebView` problem that you cite is for devices, not apps. IOW, the fix is to update the Android System WebView app on your device.

Comment: https://support.google.com/android/thread/103561027?hl=en

Comment: This is not good for 2 reasons:

1. i will lose users if the app simply not works - maybe they will not update that WebView - my app should work anyways without forcing users to update anything.

2. IF i run on same device my 21 march build that runs smoothly without any errors(!), so it should not be the device but my Webview implementation during build - that comes from the android libraries.

Comment: Everyone else got hit by this too, and even if it's Google's fault you get most of the blame when your app does not work. WebView as a dynamic dependency is great when it works. I don't know of a good alternative of replacing it with a statically linked WebView implementation, but at least in theory it is possible. Anyway, you will still have other dynamic parts in your supply chain from user point of view and there are other dependencies that might break one day.

Comment: thanks! so we dont have fixed version that can come dynamically? So the suggestion is puttin in statically? moreover: simply to forget using webwiew? (btw is there suggested alterantive to vebview?)

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

now the worst thing happened: i think my phone updated the webview - so now all builds are working... (pre 22 march, after 22 march builds)

so from now i can not detect if the dynamic library is fixed, so i might get negative reviews and lost users if their phone not yet updated the webview...

but i guess i have nothing to do here - at least i will not be able to detect if the dynamic library is fixed or not.